# Go can't call c++ function

Tags: go, cgo

I have been using cgo to interface between Go and C. However, when trying to do the same for Go and C++, I get a compile error every time I attempt to call a function. Using `go build .` from the code's directory, I get the following errors:

```
./main.go: In function 'void _cgo_3612c872201c_Cfunc_getint(void*)':
./main.go:48:53: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to '_cgo_3612c872201c_Cfunc_getint(void*)::<anonymous struct>*' [-fpermissive]
./main.go:54:4: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to '_cgo_3612c872201c_Cfunc_getint(void*)::<anonymous struct>*' [-fpermissive]
```

I've put a super simple example below which shows the problem.

main.go:

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -x c++

int getint()
{
    return 1;
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(C.getint())
}
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug in cgo, or something wrong with how I wrote the code? According to the [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/), C++ is supported. I'm using Go version 1.7.5 for linux/amd64.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think `cgo` supports C++ only in the sense it knows how to invoke a C++ compiler on the non-Go files which looks like containing C++ source code, and that's all.

The problem is that C++ compilers use so-called ["mangling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C.2B.2B) for the symbols made exported from the compiled files.  Exporting symbols were originally
intended only for C-like languages, where all which can be exported are plain
functions and variables, but C++ adds classes and function overloading,
and to export such symbols from compiled ("object") files, a C++ compiler
needs to "mangle" them using certain schema to encode names of classes
and types of arguments in these names.  What's worse, each C++ compiler
brand uses its own mangling schemas.

So I think while `cgo` is able to compile C++ code, it sort of assumes that
all the symbols exported (to be used by Go) in your C++ files are
wrapped in `extern "C" { ... }` (see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage)).

If you need calls to "native" C++ exported stuff, you'd need to use
[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Go.html) I reckon.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks so much for the help!